# How am I supposed to use setcontentview(r.layout.activity_main) Multiple times

Tags: android

this is my below code i want to switch between activity_main and  activity_second multiple times but it is giving me error

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button buttonMain, buttonSecond;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMain);
        buttonSecond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSecond);

        buttonMain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_second); //
            }
        });

        buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: You can't do that. Just use an intent to switch between activities instead.

Comment: "Giving me error" is not a very good error description. Posted my answer based on an assumption what your problem is. Please be specific when describing your problems on SO.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setContentView()`, the view hierarchy that is displayed in the activity is replaced with a new one. Therefore the buttons you had in the previous view are gone too, together with their click listeners. So after calling `setContentView()`, you need to refresh any view references with `findViewById()` and reset any click listeners.

For more Android-y view hierarchy replacement at runtime, consider using fragments, with one fragment for your activity_main layout and another for your activity_second.